# Unable to recieve notification in IOS xamarin form

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed app for ios and android in xamarin form cross platform. The problem I am facing in notification is that i can receive notification in android and its working absolutely fine, even I can open specific page from notification data, but in IOS I am not able to receieve notification. Here is my code from where I am sending notification

```
   public async void NewTaskNotification(string user_token, string titlee, string bodyy, string openpage, long? mrno, DateTime? appointmentdate)
    {
        i++;
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var objNotification = new
        {
            to = user_token,
            data = new
            {
                title = titlee,
                body = bodyy,
                priority = "high",
                id = i,
                icon = "ic_stat_ic_stat_ic_notification",
                color = "#2F3C51",
                Background = "#2F3C51",
                open_page = openpage,
                mr_no = mrno,
                appointmentDate = appointmentdate,
            },
        };
        string jsonNotificationFormat = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objNotification);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationFormat);
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AAAAoQ445fk:APA91bHagr12v6bGUqE2d8soHCMXwo4rD6wyM_LFp6yD9b968J3SQQ9u8T5rsFBtsPzL-ct_cCjad_YPpEjaw5tq_OqR_asB5-zgKqyQfhV2djFxAAbK7PBPCZHMI2Y6KmNN8R-MItOA"));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "691728344569"));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String responseFromFirebaseServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        FCMResponse response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMResponse>(responseFromFirebaseServer);
                        if (response.success == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("succeeded");
                        }
                        else if (response.failure == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("failed");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

with this code i am able to recieve notification and even open specific page but only with android, its not working with ios, but when i try to send notification to IOS from firebase console, its working fine.

Here is my appdelegate.cs

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            CachedImageRenderer.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(launchOptions, true);
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
        }
        public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        {
            public UserNotificationCenterDelegate()
            {
            }

            public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
            {
                // Do something with the notification
                Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);

                // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
                // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
            }
        }
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
    }
```

I need to know where I am doing wrong for IOS

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial? Have you set the Google.json, the correct permissions in the application?

Comment: yes i have checked everything, i am getting token for ios as i said that from firebase console ios recieving notification

Comment: Can you provide the code in UserNotificationCenterDelegate?